# Image Magick writing file to folder

Tags: php, imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use Image Magick to write a file to a specific location, and use uniqid() to give a unique filename (as I expect many images to be uploaded).

Heres what I have so far:

```
$targetdir = '/var/www/html/uploads/';
$targetfile = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($targetfile,$targetdir);

$image = new Imagick($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$uid = uniqid();

$image->setImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$image->scaleImage(80,80);
$image->setFilename($uid);

$_FILES['image']->writeImageFile($targetdir);
```

The file is originally a JPEG.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with nescessary delegates for the images.

The error I am recieving is:

```
 Call to a member function writeImageFile() on a non-object
```

Which is using the variable $targetdir - however according to php.net documentation writeImageFile should have a target directory to write the image.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can't set the filename - which should be a string - to the result of `uniquid()` - which is a number.

Comment: How would I go about giving an image a unique ID? I have removed that line of code and the error doesn't change

Comment: Something like `$uniquename=sprintf("%d.jpg",uniqid());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling

```
$image->writeImage($targetdir.$uid.".jpg");
```

instead of

```
$_FILES['image']->writeImageFile($targetdir);
```

Comment: Solved the issue straight away, life saver!